# creating ordered selections in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How do you generate order selections in MATLAB. I need to create all permutations of a word where order is important.
So with the word 'time' if you want all ordered selection of 2 letters.
You should receive

```
q=

em
ei
et
me
mi
mt
im
ie
it
tm
ti
te
```

I can only do this for 4 letter words using code like this.

```
P = perms(S);
r = size(P);
if length(S) == k
    perms(S);
else
    q = P(1:2:r,1:k)
```

but I need to generate it for all lengths of words (up to 10) and for any number up to the end of the word.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`perms`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) and [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
word = 'time';
result = perms(word);
result = unique(result(:,1:2),'rows');
```

In your example, this gives

```
>> result

result =

ei
em
et
ie
im
it
me
mi
mt
te
ti
tm
```

---

If you want multiple occurrences of the same letter in a word to be counted distinctly: work with indices, not with the letters:

```
word = 'timid';
ind = perms(1:length(word));
ind = unique(ind(:,1:2),'rows');
result = word(ind);
```

For example, with the word "timid" this gives

```
>> result

result =

ti
tm
ti
td
it
im
ii
id
mt
mi
mi
md
it
ii
im
id
dt
di
dm
di
```

Comment: Could you walk me through what's happening in the final line? Thank you!

Comment: The second line will filter out all repeated rows of the first 2 letters of the result. For example: 'mite' and 'miet' have the same first two letters, so you'll end up with only one 'mi'.

Comment: Does (:,1:2) mean all instances between columns 1 and 2?

Comment: (:,1:2) Means: `All rows`, `Columns 1 through 2`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly R. Schifini and Dennis have explained it very well while I was away :-) Thanks guys!

Comment: The formula for calculating ordered selections is N!/(N-k)! where N is the number of letters and k is the number of letters you've selected. I believe the Unique function stops this calculation from being true if you use a word with mulitples of the same letter. So 'Time' works. but Timid doesn't. Timid should generate 20 but it only creates 13 entries. Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Work with indices instead of with letters. Please see second part of updated answer